# How can checkbox calls php code then get back the results to be printed in textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am developing SMS sender form. The form has three components:

- Textarea for receiver numbers.
- Textarea for the massage content.
- checkbox which includes subscriber as receivers.

Then I was thinking that I need to go in three steps:

1- Check if the checkbox is checked.

2- Read the database for the subscriber numbers.

3- write the subscribers into receiver textarea.

What I had done was creating JavaScript function which called by the checkbox when change, then calling the php code by JavaScript function and lastly, using JavaScript inside php to append numbers into the textarea. unfortunately it didn't work. I had to research and I found that I have to use ajax to call php code.

I didn't use ajax before and I think it is difficult, I am a beginner in scripting. Also, I prefer to use this way of implementing instead of reading database after submitting the form.

I am really confused what to do. This is the first time that I need to use scripts and php inside eachothers!  I need your help what is the easiest way of implementing.

New ideas and ways are welcome.

updates:

I decided to use ajax since most of you suggest.

this is form.php code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {

          var checkbox = document.getElementById('subscribers').checked;

         //Check if checkbox is checked
         if (checkbox === true) {
         //Read databank for Results
          document.getElementById("to").value = "result  should be here.";
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sms/readSubscriber.php',
                data: {'variable': dataPhp},
                complete: function(r){
                  var subscriberNumbers = r.responseText;
                   document.getElementById('to').innerHTML = subscriberNumbers;
               }
              });


         } else {
           document.getElementById("to").value = "";
         }


         }); 


         function doalert() {
         //Check if checkbox is checked
         var checkboxElem = document.getElementById("subscribers").checked;
         if (checkboxElem === true) {
         //Read databank for Results
          document.getElementById("to").value = "result  should be here.";
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sms/readSubscriber.php',
                data: {'variable': dataPhp},
                complete: function(r){
                  var subscriberNumbers = r.responseText;
                   document.getElementById('to').innerHTML = subscriberNumbers;
               }
              });


         } else {
           document.getElementById("to").value = "";
         }

         }


      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <fieldset style="width:50%;margin:auto" dir=ltr>
         <form action="" method="POST">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
               <tr>
                  <td>Your Balance</td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Balance" size="20" disabled="disabled" value="<?php
                     echo $Credits;
                     ?>"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Mobile No.</td>
                  <td><textarea textarea class="form-control" id="to" name="Mobile" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br></td>
                  <td>
                     <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="subscribers"  onchange="doalert()" id="subscribers" checked>Subscribers</label>
                     </div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Message</td>
                  <td><textarea class="form-control" name="Text" cols="30" rows="5" required></textarea></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input type="submit" name="Go" value="Send SMS" /></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
      </fieldset>
   </body>
</html>
```

and this is the readSubscriber.php

```
<?php
require_once('../db_functions.php');

// Connect to the database
$connection = db_connect();
//if connection fails, stop script execution
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();

} else {

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM phoneSubscribers";
    // Query the database
    $result = db_isExist($query);

    if ($result) {
        $result = db_fetch($query);
        echo json_encode($result);
    } else {
        echo "No result";
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which specific part of your code is giving you headaches?

Comment: PHP runs on the server not the client, before the page or data is sent to the client.  So yes, you need to use AJAX to call some PHP script on the server, then have client scripting to display the results.  It sounds like you need to learn to use AJAX as your next step.  Tip:  the PHP that you call with AJAX does not need to be the same URL as your page.  For example the user might go to sender-form.php but then the AJAX request goes to send-one-message.php .

Comment: Also, please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] to see what kinds of questions to ask and how to ask them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Question with code, otherwise its hard to help. 
For this you have to use Ajax & jquery.

Make sure you have jquery installed.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkboxInput').checked;

//Maybe you want to pass something to the PHP file? 
var dataPhp = "";

//Check if checkbox is checked
if (checkbox === true) {
  //Read databank for Results
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'yourFile.php',
          data: {'variable': dataPhp},
          complete: function(r){
            var subscriberNumbers = r.responseText;
             document.getElementById('receivers').innerHTML = subscriberNumbers;
         }
        });
}
```

to get the variable you send to the php file, you just have to use

```
$dataFromScript = $_POST['variable'];
```

In `yourFile.php` you have to get the wanted values of the MySQL databank.

If its an array make sure to encode it with JSON.

```
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

After that, the `$resultArray` variable will be displayed in your

```
 <div id="receivers"></div>
```

Comment: I added your code into mine however ajax function maybe not executed or executed but do nothing.